# Angular routerLink relative to a variable route parameter

Tags: angular, router, angular-routerlink

I have an Angular app where the root directory is a variable route parameter:

```
/:demo_profile/(etc).
```

I cannot use relative path because my routerLink is available from different components/routes.

How can I set a `routerLink` target that is relative to the root of my site, followed by this param? i.e.

```
/SomeRoute/home
```

My routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':demo_profile',   
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',    
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'cards',    
        component: CardsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'card/:id',    
        component: CardComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'help',    
        component: HelpComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',    
        redirectTo: ':demo_profile',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '\**',    
    redirectTo: '/DGInsureCo/home',
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not ideal, a solution consists in fetching the current URL path and then reconstruct the router link as per the below:

routerLink in the template:

```
<a routerLink="/{{demo_profile}}/home">Home</a>
```

and then reference `this.demo_profile` using `activatedRoute`:

```
this.route.params.subscribe( params =>
      this.demo_profile = params['demo_profile']
    )
```

or:

```
activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path
```